# Laravel: How to fix "the MAC is invalid" on local environment

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I'm fairly new to PHP and Laravel. I'm working on a website on my local machine, and testing the admin panel portion of the website. There is a link that allows the administrator to login as a different (non-admin) user directly without having to enter their username or password. This link works fine in production but on my local server, I'm getting the error: Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The MAC is invalid. I've gathered that this likely has to do with the middleware or encryption not being set up properly on my local environment, but I don't know how to fix this.

Here is the source code of the link that is not working:

`<a href="{{ route('admin_accounts_login_as') }}/{{ $user->user_id }}/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Login As User">`

And this is the function that is throwing the error:

```
protected function getJsonPayload($payload)

    {

        $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

 

        // If the payload is not valid JSON or does not have the proper keys set we will

        // assume it is invalid and bail out of the routine since we will not be able

        // to decrypt the given value. We'll also check the MAC for this encryption.

        if (! $this->validPayload($payload)) {

            throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');

        }

 

        if (! $this->validMac($payload)) {

            throw new DecryptException('The MAC is invalid.');

        }

 

        return $payload;

    }
```

How would I go about setting up this function to work on a local environment?

Thanks

I've tried clicking the link and I expected it to log me in as the desired user. Instead I got the error message shown above. I've tried researching what the error message means, but have not figured out what I need to change to fix it. I've also tried clearing the cache/cookies and running php artisan key:generate but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: a common issue, when you try to decrypt the string using the different platform, maybe  its because of different app key, but if you are on local, this issue occurs due to string encryption on different software e.g. postman and string decryption on different env e.g. browser (if the string is encrypted on postman, it will only be decrypted on postman and same for browser and localhost). you can use a new table which save a 64 bit strings against the user id, and use this user id in routes, and easy and time saving solution.

Comment: You'll likely find a clue in your route definitions.